# panelAR doesn't recognise my coulmn as an integer

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

https://easyupload.io/3rnesm

So I'm working with the following data set:

```
# A tibble: 1,136 x 17
   ccode  year vanhdemo pcgnp  left ainew sdnew milctr2 britinfl  lpop  iwar  cwar popinc pcginc polrtnew lag_ainew lag_sdnew
   <dbl> <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     2  1980     18.7  11.3     0     1     1       0        1  19.2     0     0   1.01   7.51        7        NA        NA
 2     2  1981     18.7  12.3     0     1     1       0        1  19.3     0     0   1.01   7.99        7         1         1
 3     2  1982     18.7  13.2     0     1     1       0        1  19.3     0     0   1.01   7.39        7         1         1
 4     2  1983     18.7  14.2     0     1     1       0        1  19.3     0     0   1.01   7.69        7         1         1
 5     2  1984     16.1  15.5     0     1     1       0        1  19.3     0     0   1.01   9.66        7         1         1
 6     2  1985     16.1  16.5     0     1     1       0        1  19.3     0     0   1.01   6.24        7         1         1
 7     2  1986     16.1  17.5     0     1     1       0        1  19.3     0     0   1.01   5.86        7         1         1
 8     2  1987     16.1  18.6     0     2     2       0        1  19.3     0     0   1.01   6.39        7         1         1
 9    20  1980     25.6  10.2     0     1     1       0        1  17.0     0     0   1.08   9.01        7        NA        NA
10    20  1981     25.6  10.7     0     1     1       0        1  17.0     0     0   1.08   5.77        7         1         1
# ... with 1,126 more rows
```

As you can see, R recognises the variable `year` as an integer. Originally, the column values were numerical, but I converted them to integer. However, when I run the following code (using the panelAR package), I run into trouble:

```
panelAR(vanhdemo ~ pcgnp + left + lpop + iwar + milctr2 + britinfl, data = dat, 
        panelVar = "ccode", timeVar = "year", autoCorr = "psar1", panelCorrMethod = "pcse",
        rho.na.rm = TRUE, panel.weight = "t-1", bound.rho = TRUE)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: The time variable must be defined as an integer.
```

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here. If I recreate a part of the data set (as below), the model runs fine. So is the problem then rooted in the data set (originally a .dta file)? I can definitely upload it if anyone is interested in looking at it.

Here's a small example of the same data:

```
ccode  <- c(rep(2,8), rep(20, 2))
year  <- c(1980:1987, 1980, 1981)
vanhdemo <- c(rep(18.7, 4), rep(16.1, 4), rep(25.6, 2))
pcgnp  <- c(11.3, 12.3 , 13.2, 14.2, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5, 18.6, 10.2, 10.7)

dat <- data.frame(ccode, year, vanhdemo, pcgnp)
```

Comment: Maybe if the class of year from `dat` is numeric, not integer and `panelAR` works, try changing the class of year in your data back to numeric.

Comment: @sm0k313 I tried the second suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Don't if this would matter for panelAR(), but your first object is a tibble, but 'dat' is a  data.frame. Maybe try converting the real data to a data.frame?

Comment: @xilliam you've got eyes like a hawk. That was the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has to do with the different behavior of `data.frames` and `tibbles`. Tibbles are a [special kind of data.frame](https://r4ds.github.io/bookclub-tmwr/tibbles-vs-data-frames.html) that 'prevent dimension dropping'. If you try to subset a tibble with a single column name,
you will get back a single-column tibble. Yet depending on how you subset a data.frame, you may get back a vector or a data.frame. The error you see results from this distinction. Internally `panelAR()` subsets the data object for the time variable:

```
time.vec <- data[, timeVar]
```

So, if 'data' is a tibble, 'time.vec' will be a single-column tibble, whereas
if 'data' is a data.frame, 'time.vec' will be a vector. `panelAR()` then
checks if 'time.vec' is an integer vector, and throws the error in cases where the data object is a tibble.

You can see this behavior in your sample data as follows:

```
# make a tibble 
dat_tib <- tibble::as_tibble(dat)

# returns a vector
dat[, "year"]

# returns a data.frame
dat["year"]

# returns a tibble
dat_tib[, "year"]

# returns a tibble
dat_tib["year"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer in in comment by @xilliam. Solution was to convert table from tibble to data frame.